# Remove specific part of a variable in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a python code in order to transform:

```
scaffold_356_1-1000_+__Genus_species
```

into

```
scaffold_356_Gen_spe
```

So the idea is to first reduce after the `__` part the name with the `3 first letters` so from `Genus_species` to `Gen_spe`

and remove the *number-number* part from so remove `_1-1000_+_`

Thanks for your help :)

I actually know to do:

```
import re 
name = "scaffold_356_1-1000_+__Genus_species"
name=re.sub(r'\d+\-\d*',"",name)
name = re.sub(r'__.__',"_",name)
```

and I get :

```
scaffold_356_Genus_species
```

Comment: show your code and full error message.

Comment: what is scaffold_356_1-1000_+__Genus_species? Is it a string? Are your trying to do some string transformation?

Comment: Are we talking about strings? You might want to start working with [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: I show what I tried, I'm stuck in order to reduce Genus_species to Gen_spe

Comment: Check my answer below on how to reduce `Genus_species` to `Gen_spe` @chippycentra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.  I would split the string into prefix and suffix and modify them separately, and then join them back.

```
import re
s = 'scaffold_356_1-1000_+__Genus_species'

#Split to suffix and prefix
suffix, prefix = s.split('__')
#scaffold_356_1-1000_+, Genus_species

#Get first three characters for prefix
modified_prefix = '_'.join([s[0:3] for s in prefix.split('_')])
#Gen_spe

#Do the regex replace for digits and remove the underscore and + at end of string
modified_suffix =re.sub(r'\d+\-\d*',"",suffix).rstrip('_+\\+')
#scaffold_356

#Join the strings back
final_s = modified_suffix  + '_' + modified_prefix
print(final_s)
#scaffold_356_Gen_spe
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, it is quite sensitive to the pattern of your input :

```
name = "scaffold_356_1-1000_+__Genus_species"
comp_list = name.split("_")
result = comp_list[0] + "_" + comp_list[1] + "_" + comp_list[5][0:3] + "_" + comp_list[6][0:3]
print(result) # scaffold_356_Gen_spe
```

The biggest advantage of this solution is its readability (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do patterned text manipulations, for which regular expressions are well-suited.  It's difficult to generalize from a single example -- the more precise you can describe the transformation the easier it will be to craft a regular expression to do what you want.  The Python documentation on regular expressions is a useful reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

If I had to generalize a pattern from your example and description, I would craft the following regular expression:

```py
import re

myre = re.compile(
    r'([A-Za-z]+_[\d]+)' # This will match "scaffold_356" in the first group
    r'_[\d]+-[\d]+_\+_' # This will match "_1-1000_+_" ungrouped
    r'(_[A-Za-z]{3})' # This will match _Gen and put it in the second group
    r'[A-Za-z]*' # This will match any additional letters, ungrouped
    r'(_[A-Za-z]{3})' # This will match _Gen and put it in the third group
)
```

If you then try to use this regular expression, you can see that it will pull out the parts that you want to construct into the final result:

```py
matches = myre.match('scaffold_356_1-1000_+__Genus_species')
print(''.join(matches)) # prints scaffold_356_Gen_spe
```

Of course this regular expression only works for very specific patterns, and will be unforgiving if the pattern is not strictly adhered to.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most elegant solution, but it works assuming you'll always have the pattern of string_3digits_1digit-4digits_+__string_string.

```
import re

a_string = 'scaffold_356_1-1000_+__Genus_species'

new = re.findall('^([a-zA-Z]+_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_).+?_\+__([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]).*(_[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]).*', a_string)

print(''.join(list(new[0])))
# scaffold_356_Gen_spe
```

This example uses a regex pattern with capturing groups. You might want to play around with [regex](https://regex101.com/) a little bit to understand the structure of the pattern. If you insert this regex pattern, regex101 will give you a comprehensible explanation of every single item.